# Exclude Property in Owned Entity Type

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a way to [exclude a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties#fluent-api) from an [owned entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)?

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(
    o => o.ShippingAddress,
    sa =>
    {
        sa.Property(p => p.Street).Ignore(); //doesn't compile
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(
    o => o.ShippingAddress,
    sa =>
    {
        //sa.Property(p => p.Street).Ignore(); //doesn't compile
        sa.Ignore(p => p.Street); //this works 
    });
```

[Full sample](https://github.com/spottedmahn/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/ignore-property/samples/core/Modeling/OwnedEntities/OwnedEntityContext.cs#L48) from the [EntityFramework.Docs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs)